# C++ linkeditor can't find function declaration (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, undefined-reference

I'm learning C++ and using CLion to build projects. I have the `main.cpp` file in the `main` directory. I also have a `main/Objects` directory, inside of which I have `Vec3.h` and `Vec3.cpp` files:

```
//Vec3.h
template<typename T>
class Vec3
{
public:
    // 3 most basic ways of initializing a vector
    Vec3() : x(T(0)), y(T(0)), z(T(0)) {}
    Vec3(const T &xx) : x(xx), y(xx), z(xx) {}
    Vec3(T xx, T yy, T zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}
    T x, y, z;

    T length();
};
```

.

```
//Vec3.cpp
#include "Vec3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

template <typename T>
T Vec3<T>::length()
{
    return sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
}
```

.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Objects/Vec3.h"

int main() {
    Vec3<double> vec(3, 4, 0);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec.length() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(Testing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Objects/Vec3.cpp)

add_executable(Testing ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I try to build and run, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to "Vec3<double>::length()". ld returned 1 exit status
```

What info am I not giving to the linkeditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told CMake about your header file, so you can use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html). Add the following line to the end of your `CMakeLists.txt` file, to ensure the header is included in the build:

```
target_include_directories(Testing PRIVATE Objects)
```

Also, templated definitions can typically [only be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) in header files. Move the following function definition from the `Vec3.cpp` file to the header file (`Vec3.h`):

```
template <typename T>
T Vec3<T>::length()
{
    return sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
}
```

Comment: CMake now throws the following error: "target_include_directories called with invalid arguments"

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Updated by answer. Also, make sure you add this line to the end of your `CMakeLists.txt` file, after you've called `add_executable()`.

Comment: Ok, with the PRIVATE added in CMake throws no errors. However, the undefined reference error persists

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Forgot about template definitions... In your example, `Vec3.cpp` can serve as a place-holder file, but you have to move the `length()` function definition to the header file. See the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).